# Vuejs - require component on demand

Tags: javascript, babeljs, vue.js

I'm trying to load components on demand, according with the page.
Because there is some components in database.

The user can access the page, like:

http://example.com/blog/post01

http://example.com/blog/post02

http://example.com/blog/post03

Then, I want to load the component from database according with the parameter.
post01, post02, post03

```
<template>
  <div>
  <testblock></testblock>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
  components: {
    'testblock': function (resolve) {
      console.log(this);
      /* this is just por test purpose to load the component using parameters */
      let name = 'teste';
      let path = ['./static/', name, '.html'].join('');
      console.log(path);
      require(['./database/post01.html'], resolve);
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  data: function () {
    return {
      post: 'post01'
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted: function () {

  }
};
</script>
```

But, I always getting something like 
ERROR in ..../~/babel-loader
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./database/post01.html

I Just wan't to load/require from a file that is not in project directory, like in database or another path (using nginx alias).
Is there a way to load components in this way?

Comment: What do you mean by holding a component in a database? I hope you mean the component's data is in the database, not the whole component file itself? The latter would be just bad design in my opinion. You'd want the actual files to still exist in a directory, so your loader (e.g. webpack) could fetch them quick and then inside the component (or a controller) query for its data.

Comment: I just don't want to use webpack (loader). Webpack is a new approach, it's great, but I just don't like it.

I just like to lazy load components, and made this components editable, like a CMS for components.

All backend (REST) is written in C.
I just want some html and js loaded on demand according with the user request, and the admin can change the component logic using a UI admin based.

I don't know if I made myself clear, and don't care if its a bad design.
A fell years latter, loading all in one pack was a bad thing, now guys like you are saying that this is the best way.

Comment: It's not 'guys like me' saying that it's the best way. It's the standards and new technologies dictating it. HTTP/2 benefits greatly from multiple small files instead of one monolith. Your caching also improves greatly. What's not to love? If you don't care bout bad design, I'm afraid I'm unable to help you at this point.. Also, not to sound harsh, but hope you check your tone next time you contribute on Stack Overflow. The community here is great and we're all trying to chip in for the greater good of the web.